# Pull certain lines of text out of a large group of files

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting

I am trying to yank all of the individual Unix commands out of a large group of text files.

Here is what I have so far:

In this example I am pulling out all instances of the `tx` command. 
The big group of text documents are all sitting over in `/PROJECT/DOCS`
and they are all named `whatever.EXT`.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f ~/Documents/proc-search.txt 

cd /PROJECT/DOCS

for file in *

do
 echo "PROC Name: "$file >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
 echo "Description:" >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
 awk 'NR==1' $file >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
 echo "UNIX Commands:" >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
 awk '/tx/{print}' $file >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
 echo "########################################" >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt

done
```

I opened proc-search.txt and was all excited because it did indeed grab all instances of the `tx` command.  But it also is outputting information for files I don't want because they don't include the `tx` command.  Like in `ACPFM.EXT` in the example below.  Is there a way I can make it exclude <del>fields</del> files that don't have `tx`?

This is the output I get, called proc-search.txt.  And it looks good, except for the fact that I want to NOT see any report about `ACPFM.EXT`,
or or any other .EXTs that don't use the `tx` command.

```
PROC Name: 17.EXT
Description:
* NORMPARD (EDIT CONTRL FILE)
UNIX Commands:
# tx @CONTRL                                    <- YAY!  This is a result that I want.
########################################
PROC Name: ACPFM.EXT                            <- I don't want this stanza.
Description:
* ACPFM (Account PARameter File Maintenance)
UNIX Commands:
########################################
PROC Name: ACTDARA.EXT
Description:
*
UNIX Commands:
#tx @SEQFILE                                    <- YAY!  This is a result that I want.
########################################
PROC Name: ACTEDIT.EXT
Description:
*
UNIX Commands:
#tx @SEQFILE                                    <- YAY!  This is a result that I want.
########################################
```

Comment: Please put code and logs in the appropriate code tags.

Comment: use `{}` button to mark text as code.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting issues, definite new guy here.

Comment: Possibly `awk /^# ?tx/`?   `^` will anchor to beginning of line. `?` will look for 0 or 1 occurrence of space

Comment: Are you showing us an example input file or is that the output you are getting?

Comment: Whether what you're posted is sample input or expected output please [edit] your question to include the other one, e.g. if that text block is sample input then add expected output and vice-versa.

Comment: What I showed is the output file, the contents of proc-search.txt.  17.EXT, ACTDARA.EXT, and ACTEDIT.EXT came out perfectly.  I got the PROC Name, Description (sometimes, doesn't matter much), and the tx command.  Just need a way to get rid of ACPFM.EXT, since it doesn't include the tx command.

Comment: OK, so that block of text is the actual output you get that you don't want. Fine, then please [edit] your question to add the sample input that you get that output from and the expected output that you DO want so we have something to test a potential solution with. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

your (abridged) loop

```
for file in *
do
 echo "PROC Name: "$file >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt

 awk '/tx/{print}' $file >> ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
 
done
```

will print `"PROC Name: foo"` for all files, and `awk` will only print `tx` line for a match.

maybe you want (assuming no directory match * )

```
for file in $(grep -l tx *)
```

this way all files in loop will have `tx` string.

Comment: A bit of a downer if you have a file with a space in its name

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /PROJECT/DOCS &&
awk '
    FNR==1 {
        desc = $0
        doneHdr = 0
    }
    /tx/ {
        if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
            printf "%s", sep
            sep = "########################################" ORS
            print "PROC Name:", FILENAME
            print "Description:" ORS desc
            print "UNIX Commands:"
        }
        print
    }
    END {
        printf "%s", sep
    }
' * > ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
```

but without sample input and expected output that's just an untested guess.

Answer (score 1):

Archemar has the right idea, but (IMNSHO) the wrong approach. 
I’d keep it simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

command_name=tx                 # or use "$1" if you want to be able to pass this as an arg

cd /PROJECT/DOCS  &&
for file in *
do
    if grep -q "$command_name" "$file"
    then
        echo "PROC Name: $file"
        echo "Description:"
        head -n1 "$file"
        echo "UNIX Commands:"
        grep "$command_name" "$file"
        echo "########################################"
    fi
done  > ~/Documents/proc-search.txt
```